# Vim, autoindent, xml and autoclosing tag

Tags: xml, vim, indentation

Here my vimrc

```
filetype plugin indent on
set autoindent 
set tabstop=2 
set shiftwidth=2 
set softtabstop=2
```

And that all.

Let suppose I start a new xml file.

WHen a use normal tag, autoindent work well

```
<div>
  <p> 
     Some text
  </p>
</div>
```

But if I insert autoclosing tags, autoindnet don't recognize the autoclosing feature,and I get something like this.

```
<div>
  <p> 
     Some text<lb />
        Some text<lb />
             Some text<lb />
  </p>
</div>
```

I use vim 8.1.2269. I tried with nvim 0.4.3 > same problem. WHat is strange is that in the past (before my new fresh installation of Ubuntu), I didn't get any problem...

Comment: Could it be because you are not closing the `<p>` ?

Comment: nope, it was a mistake in my sample code, but in real life, it is closed ans same problem,

Answer (score 0):

Yes was a bug, solved by the maintener.

https://github.com/chrisbra/vim-xml-runtime/issues/25